# Use order by statement as parameter in a parameterized query

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform

I'm struggling to use a dynamic `order by` statement in a parameterized query of Google BigQuery NodeJS API.

I want to achieve this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT col1, col2, col3, date FROM table ORDER BY ? DESC LIMIT ? OFFSET ?;
```

with following parameters array:

```
[ 'date', 10, 0 ]
```

But the `order by` statement is ignored.
I'm adding the parameters like this:

```
params.push(orderBy ?? "date", limit ?? 10, offset ?? 0);
```

---

**However**, the following query is working:

```
    SELECT DISTINCT col1, col2, col3, date FROM table ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT ? OFFSET ?;
```

with following parameters array:

```
[ 10, 0 ]
```

the `order by` statement works.

I think it's a problem of format of the `order by` parameter because `limit` and `offset` parameters are working.

Thank you in advance with any help you can bring.